# Can I run JSShaper in the browser?

Tags: javascript

You can run [JSShaper](http://jsshaper.org/) from the command line like this:

```
d8 run-shaper.js -- filename [plugin1 .. pluginN]
```

Is there a way to embed the script in my website and run it when the page loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can run JSShaper in browser. 
See http://restrictmode.org/ where they are using a 'restricter' plugin.There is a demo provided which you can try in your browser. You can write plugins for your own purposes.

Answer (score 0):

From the [JSShaper README](https://github.com/olov/jsshaper/blob/master/README#L45):

> JSShaper is designed to run **from the command line**. It should be
>   possible to use with the following JS shells:
>
> - js: recent versions of Mozilla SpiderMonkey
> - d8: Google V8 debug shell
> - node: Embedded V8 with lots more

Comment: What if I change some of the source code of JSShaper so that it parses a string instead of a file. Can I then run it in the browser or does it use some special features of command line js versions.